# How to make a matrix of random values in NetLogo?

Tags: matrix, netlogo

Is there a way to easily make an $n \cross m$ matrix in NetLogo? Additionally would it be possible to fill this matrix with random values? Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried or researched? As it is, you're simply asking for code without showing minimal understanding of the problem at hand, which makes the post off topic for SO.

Answer (score 2):

*this answer has been updated for NetLogo 6 task syntax*

See http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/matrix.html for docs on NetLogo's matrix extension.

For creating a matrix, there are several primitives that do that: `matrix:make-constant`, `matrix:make-identity`, `matrix:from-row-list`, `matrix:from-column-list`.

For creating a matrix and filling it with random values, I'd suggest defining this procedure first:

```
to-report fill-matrix [n m generator]
  report matrix:from-row-list n-values n [n-values m [runresult generator]]
end
```

Then to make, say, a 5 by 5 matrix, of, say, random integers in the range 0 to 9, it's:

```
fill-matrix 5 5 [-> random 10]
```

Example result:

```
observer> show fill-matrix 5 5 [-> random 10]
observer: {{matrix:  [ [ 5 9 3 2 6 ][ 5 8 2 8 0 ][ 6 7 3 7 4 ][ 7 0 4 6 3 ][ 7 9 0 0 5 ] ]}}
```